# How to subscriber angularFireMessaging messages

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification

I am using fire base notification for the push notification. I am able to get push notification pop up when ever new notification arrives but not getting application control in message subscriber method.

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.pushNotificationService.requestPermission();
  this.pushNotificationService.receiveMessage();
  this.message = this.pushNotificationService.currentMessage;
 }
```

PushNotificationService.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
 import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';
 import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
 @Injectable()
 export class PushNotificationService {
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(
   private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging,
   private notificationService: NotificationService
   ) {
      this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(message => {
      console.log('new message received in cons. ', message?.data);
      console.log(message);
      });
    }

    requestPermission() {
      this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
         (token: any) => {
           this.notificationService
             .subscribe(token)
             .pipe(first())
             .subscribe({
                next: data => {
                  console.log('Token is: ' + token);
                },
                error: error => {
                 console.log(error);
                },
             });
          },
          (err: any) => {
           console.log(error);
           }
        );
     }

       receiveMessage() {
          this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload: any) => {
             console.log('new message received. ', payload);
             this.currentMessage.next(payload?.data);
          });
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below settings worked for me

version in package.json :

```
"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1"
 "firebase": "^9.9.3"
```

Structure of firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'adkadgakhdgjdjagdj',
  authDomain: 'fir-c0b2b.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com',
  projectId: 'fir-ckhdsahk',
  storageBucket: 'fir-sdkjash.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '64828400',
  appId: '1:75347959:web:4ad4490a8ecbe5539b25ad',
  measurementId: 'G-GFHFH',
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log("subscriber the push notification when application in background");
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
});
```

Code in messageService.ts

```
receiveMessage() {
 console.log('Receive push notification message when application is in foreground');
 this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload: any) => {
 console.log('new message received. ', payload);
});
```